# Why does my php file not run on xamppp?

Tags: php, xampp

I am learning some basic PHP and already installed Xampp, but my php file did not show up correctly as it should when I opened it in localhost.
This my php code: http://prntscr.com/n8zvwn
and this is what it shown on localhost: http://prntscr.com/n8zw8s
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP file *runs* perfectly fine. If it weren't processed through the PHP interpreter, you'd see the whole original code in the browser (e.g. through "View Source") – but right now you're seeing just the proper output of the code.

`{a}` and `{b}` are not replaced with variable contents because that's not the correct variable expansion syntax [according to PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). Variables inside a double-quoted string literal must be specified as one of:

- `$var` (e.g. `echo "Hello $a"`);
- `${var}` (e.g. `echo "Hello ${a}"`);
- `{$var}` (e.g. `echo "Hello {$a}"`).